# HTML code for a form to send email through SMTP server

Tags: smtp

Another newbie question...
I want to create a simple form where the user enters an email recipient in a field and then send the email.
The subject is a fixed text. The body message is also a fixed text but with one parameter that is entered from the user.

I have an SMTP exchange service gateway for that called "smtp-gw.domain.com"
and a non reply mailbox to send these emails called "donotreply@domain.com" that uses no password since it will be used inside the company.

An example output is like the image

Thanks you guys in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpcUv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with just an HTML form (apart from using a mailto: -link, but that does not let you specify the email body).

You need to have some kind of server side script that receives the HTML form data and submits an email using SMTP or with some command-line mail-submission program. So this depends entirely on the kind of web server you are using and what capabilities your web server environment has.

Comment: I have available one MS IIS 7.0 server

Comment: Just Google for "FormMail" and you will get plenty of scripts to choose from. E.g. http://thegustfactor.blogspot.fi/2014/11/aspx-formmail-script-for-windows.html is just one of many. Note that the simplest scripts can have flawed security that allow spammers to misuse the script!